A question about coprime automorphisms of profinite groups
Let $p$ a prime. A finite group is a $p'$-group if its order is prime to $p$. Let $A$ be a finite $p'$-group of automorphisms of a finite $p$-group $G$. Suppose that $A$ is a non-cyclic abelian group. It's proved in [Theorem 3.16, Chapter 5, Daniel Gorenstein. Finite groups. Chelsea Publishing Co., New York, second edition, 1980.] that
$$ G=\prod_{a\in A^{\# }}C_G(a),$$
where $A^{\#}$ denotes the set of non-trivial elements of $A$, and $C_G(a)=\{g\in G~|~a(g)=g\}$ denotes the fixed points of $a$. Moreover, it's claimed in [Lemma 2.5(iv), Pavel Shumyatsky. Profinite groups in which many elements have prime power order. J. Algebra, 562: 188-199, 2020] that the above statement still holds for infinite profinite group, i.e. we have the following:

Let $A$ be a finite group of automorphisms of a pro-$p$ group $G$. Suppose that $A$ is a non-cyclic finite abelian $p'$-group. Then we have $G=\prod_{a\in A^{\# }}C_G(a)$.

I suspect that this statement is not true for infinite profinite groups. Take $G$ to be a non-solvable just-infinite pro-$p$ group such that there exists a non-cyclic abelian $p'$-group $A$ acting faithfully on $G$. For example, take $G={\rm SL}_{2}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_{p}):=\ker({\rm SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})\twoheadrightarrow {\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})) $ to be the first congruence special linear group over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers for $p>2$. Then the Sylow $2$-subgroup $S_2$ of projective special linear group ${\rm PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ acts faithfully by conjugation on $G$. (One can show $S_2$ contains a non-cyclic abelian subgroup.)  Such a group cannot be written as $\prod_{a\in A^{\#}} C_G(a)$. Indeed, there are at least two non-trivial elements $a_1,a_2$ of $A$ such that $C_G(a_i)\neq 1$. (Otherwise, G is nilpotent by Thompson's theorem). But then it follows that $G$ is virtually abelian because $G$ is just-infinite, a contradiction. Is my understanding correct?

What does the product mean? Smallest group containing each subgroup, or literally the set of products in some (fixed?) order?

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Your example is definitely not a counterexample. A noncyclic abelian $2$-subgroup of $\PSL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is a Klein four group. Each nontrivial element lifts to an element $i$ of order four in $\SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$. Its centralizer in $\SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is the set of matrices $a+bi$, $a,b\in \mathbb Z_p$, $a^2+b^2=1$. The intersection with the principal congruence subgroup imposes the further conditions $a\equiv 1\bmod p, b\equiv 0\bmod p$, which imply $a\equiv 1\bmod p^2$.
The abelianization of the principle congruence subgroup is $\mathbb F_p^3$, with the map to the abelianization explicitly presented by subtracting $1$, dividing by $p$, and then taking the congruence class mod $p$, a $2\times 2$ matrix of trace zero over $\mathbb F_p$. Applied to $a+bi$, this produces $\frac{b}{p} i$. We can indeed find a solution with $b\neq 0\bmod p^2$.
For the product of the $C_G(a)$s to span the abelianization of $G$, it suffices for the three of order $4$ to span the matrices of trace zero over $\mathbb F_p$. It is easy to see that they do this - one way is by interpreting two by two matrices over $\mathbb Z_p$ as quaternions, and noting that $i,j,k$ span the quaternions of trace $0$.
I think the problem is on this step: "But then it follows that $G$ is virtually abelian because $G$ is just-infinite."
What is the argument there?

I misunderstood this product. I thought it was a direct product, but it is actually just a product.

the argument in my mind is the following: If $G$ is a direct product of some non-trivial $C_G(a_i)$, then $G$ must be finite because $G$ is just-infinite and each $C_G(a_i)$ is a closed normal subgroup.

Moreover, we have the following lemma: Let $G$ be a just-infinite profinite group, and $H$ a normal closed subgroup such that the centralizer $C_G(H)$ of $H$ in $G$ is non-trivial. Then $C_G(H)$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ of finite index. Proof: Note $C_G(H)$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ which implies it has finite index in $G$. Put $C:=C_G(H)$. Then $C\cap H$ has finite index in $C$, and $[C:Z(C)]\leq [C:C\cap H]<\infty$ where $Z(C)$ is the center of $C$. It follows that the derived subgroup $[C,C]$ of $C$ is finite. Since $G$ is just-infinite, $[C,C]$ is trivial.
